# Buttons are opening the same modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using 2 modals on my page. I open these modals with a buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn1">Modal 1</button>
<button type="button" id="myBtn2">Modal 2</button>
```

When I click on the buttons the buttons are opening the same modal. How can I fix that?

Here are the modals

**Modal1:**

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">
        <div class="x_content">                  
          <p>content modal 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Modal2:**

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">
        <div class="x_content">                  
          <p>content modal 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script Modal 1:**

```
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Script Modal 2:**

```
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How are you loading these scripts? Change the variable name of the second modal from "var modal" to var modal2

Comment: because the `modal` you're always calling, is going to be the latest one you've assigned, which would probably be `myModal2`

Comment: @karthick Changing the variable name worked. Thanks

Comment: your welcome. have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont var the same name for modal and btn.

try

```
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put private function

```
(function(){
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal2');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
     var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = modal.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];//<<<<pay attention here
    ...
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off actually assigning the elements per `btn.onclick`. You're calling the global variable modal, which will use the most recently assigned value.

```
// for first script
btn.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("myModal1").style.display = "block";
}


// for second script
btn.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("myModal2").style.display = "block";
}
```